# Export object with its related objects from a database in Django

Tags: python, django, model

What is the fastest way to export an object with all its relations from a database? I want to use it as a fixture for my tests. Now I call `manage.py dumpdata <my_app>.<my_model> --pks <pks>` for each model separately, but it takes a lot of time. Is there a smarter way of doing this task?

Lets say we have this hierarchy of models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class PartsToOrder(models.Model):
    type = modles.CharField(max_length=255)
    car = models.ForeignKey('Car', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

How could I export car object with `id = 3528`, including all parts to order and its owner into one fixture file.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a custom management command which runs the command above within a for loop. That for loop would iterate a list of app/model combinations. You could extend it from there. That would automate the process.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html

Comment: I wonder if there already is an implementation of this kind of tool. In my case, model hierarchy is quite complex with multiple `ForeignKey`, `ManyToMany` fields and I think it would be easier to write a generic command, which automatically detects all the relations and includes them, than hardcoding the names of each relation in my custom management command.